# Postgres SQL to extract rows based on sequence number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have  data in Telephone table, something as below:

| ID | area | exch | line | ext | tel_type_cde | tel_seq_num | modified_dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 482 | 876 | 789 | 1234 | 0 | 0 | 01-01-2023 |
| 1234 | 483 | 877 | 123 |  | 0 | 1 | 01-02-2023 |
| 1234 | 123 | 234 | 456 | 1234 | 1 | 0 | 01-01-2023 |
| 1235 | 483 | 877 | 456 |  | 0 | 1 | 01-01-2023 |
| 1236 | 483 | 877 | 123 |  | 0 | 0 | 01-02-2023 |
| 1236 | 123 | 234 | 456 | 1234 | 0 | 1 | 01-02-2023 |
| 1236 | 483 | 877 | 458 |  | 0 | 2 | 01-03-2023 |

For an ID/tel_type_cde combination there might be multiple rows and telephone sequence number  is used to derive from latest number which needs to considered further

Expected output

| ID | area | exch | line | ext | tel_type_cde |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 483 | 877 | 123 |  | 0 |
| 1234 | 123 | 234 | 456 | 1234 | 1 |
| 1235 | 483 | 877 | 456 |  | 0 |
| 1236 | 483 | 877 | 458 |  | 0 |

Drafted below query so far, but not working as expected

```
select distinct on (ID)
ID,
area,
exch,
line,
ext,
tel_type_cde
from telephone 
order by ID,tel_seq_num desc;
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, tel_type_cde)
       id, area, exch, line, ext, tel_type_cde
  FROM telephone
 ORDER BY id, tel_type_cde, tel_seq_num DESC ;
```

Comment: Thanks, working as expected -[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/pZ902kGz)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RANK window function with a common table expression to get the expected results

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT ID,  area,   exch,   line,   ext,    tel_type_cde, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, tel_type_cde ORDER BY tel_seq_num DESC) as r
FROM telephone
)
SELECT
ID, area,   exch,   line,   ext,    tel_type_cde
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cnWsy3a7FPohkMVCYz9gES/0)